# Using fragments as activities in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

- I am currently having a mainactivity which holds another five activities in a listview. Upon clicking it will open the corresponding activities.
- I actually want to use tabs with viewpager.
- Now, Do I need to start my activities when clicking on each tabs
  or I have to keep one activity and pass only the fragment to the
  viewpager?

Comment: You have to pass instance of FragmentPagerAdapter to ViewPager, it will handle rest. Check this great tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: Thanks!. So, Now I can have only one mainactivity and pass all other activities as fragment from adaptor right?. Now, they activities are converted into fragments right. So, If I swipe between the tabs then the viewpager which holds the fragments also changes. is it  like i am creating my 6 activities as fragments?

Comment: Yeah you have to extend Fragment instead of Activity in that child activities. And you will have one MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks @OzgurGUL. Can u provide me some link to the above concept. Not connecting tabs with viewpager and passing the fragments. Some real  examples. for instance, get all contacts and show in listview in first fragment. like this performing something in the fragment and returning the date to the viewpager